# How to import custom svg icon in Vuex (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, svg, icons, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

How to import custom svg icon in Vuex (using Vuetify and Nuxt.js)

in Vuetify.options:

```
icons: {
    values: {
      myIcon: {
        component: awesomeIcon
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons/#using-custom-icons) You would import the icon in the config file (for vuetify) and add it to the vuetify bootstrap as you did. Although you would need to have a default for all icons as shown in the docs above.

Basically should look something like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import myImportedIcon from 'someplace'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'fa',
    values: {
      myIcon: myImportedIcon
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: I understand that, thanks. Question is how to use that icon in Vuex. 
    in vue app it can be done via $vuetify.icons.awesomeIcon
    I need that Icons import to Vuex (that's for State. Ordinary Icons imported well, but custom won't)

Comment: curious, what is your use case that you need the icon (as an icon) in vuex, wouldn't. an icon be something you display in the template? (I understand you may want to have the string of the icon saved in the store but why the icon itself)

Comment: I need not icon itself, but string in Vuex,

Comment: so just commit that string to your store, why can't you do that?
In your app.vue put in the `created` method a "SET_ICONS" commit to your store.(or wherever you want really)